# numpy addition between different dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, dimensions

I am running the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([[1, 2]])
a = a + b

print(a)
[[2 , 4 ]]
```

As you can see. dimension of `a` is 1, and `b` is 2.

Mathematically, it is not possible to add between different dimensional arrays
how can it work under the numpy? and what does that mean [ [ 2, 4 ] ]?

- a.shape is (2, )
- b.shape is (1 ,2)
- (a+b).shape is (1 ,2)

However the following code yields an error:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([[1, 2]])
a += b
```

Why doesn't it work? What makes different result?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: According to broadcasting rules a (2,) can expand to (1,2).  But in the `+=` only the RHS can be adjusted.  The LHS (`a`) is fixed.   A (1,2) cannot be put in a (2,).

Answer (score 0):

As already implied in the comments, it always helps to check the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html); quoting:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal,
> 2. **or one of them is 1**

In your case both of the arrays share a dimension that has 1 element (1 column in A and 1 row in B).

Because of that it adds them in a way that would not make sense mathematically.

If you changed this and had arrays that share a dimension which is 1, then you would get an error.